# Trying to convert geometry to geography keep failing in MSSQL 2012

Tags: geometry, sql-server, geography

In MSSQL I have LineString in Geometry type.
When I try to convert it to geography using :

```
GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(geom.MakeValid().STUnion(geom.MakeValid().STStartPoint().MakeValid()).STAsText(),4326)
```

I still get error that

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":System.ArgumentException: 24200: The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a spatial instance to shift slightly.System.ArgumentException: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography..ctor(GeoData g, Int32 srid) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
```

Any idea how I can convert it to geography ?

Any idea how I can share the LineString ? Its very long (exceeding this post body length)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you have a minor error in your select statement. Try this:

```
GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(geom.MakeValid().STAsText(),4326)
```

What you are doing is making a union between the linestring and a point, which doesn't really work. All you want to do is make your geometry valid, then convert it to geography.

Note that geography data types need to be in lat, lon already. SQL Server wont reproject data, so if you need to do that, I'd use either org2ogr or Quantum GIS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My lat lon is already in projection 4326 , I have example of 6 linestrings , 4 valids and 2 not.
The example with the union was taken from example here :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edkatibah/archive/2008/08/19/working-with-invalid-data-and-the-sql-server-2008-geography-data-type-part-1b.aspx

Comment: @Alegleith : I get the following error Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
System.ArgumentException: 24200: The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a spatial instance to shift slightly.

When I check why I get error , I see this message :
24413: Not valid because of two overlapping edges in curve (1).

Comment: Alex is right that you don't need the UNION.  Ed's post was regarding an issue specific to polygons.

Comment: So why my LineString isn't working even with MakeValid? 
Here is a link to it : http://pastebin.com/VJWCtirB

Comment: It's because one of your lines has invalid geometry. You can load it into another piece of software and fix it. Opening it with QGIS and loading into GRASS works. That's hard though.

The reason for the error is that GEOGRAPHY is more picky about geometry than GEOMETRY.

Comment: @Alexgleith : Is there a way to do the fixing over SQL ?

Comment: If 'makevalid' doesn't work, then no! You could try some of these though: http://www.beginningspatial.com/fixing_invalid_geography_data